# Alternate for First_Value() in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that works well in Oracle and DB2 . But it does not work in SQL Server 2008 because First_Value function is not available with the same . Is there a work around for 2008 ?

```
select NameGuid, Name, AncestorGuid, ProductGuid, PathLength
from (
    select 
    NameGuid, 
    Name, 
    AncestorGuid, 
    ProductGuid, 
    PathLength, 
    -- take every row from original query with the same Name as this,
    -- order those rows by PathLength (and NameGuid to disambiguate)
    -- and return the NameGuid of the first row in that "partition"
    first_value(NameGuid) over (partition by Name order by PathLength asc, NameGuid asc) MinNameGuid
    from ( 
        ... your original query ...
    )
)
where 
-- return rows whose NameGuid is the same as the NameGuid calculated by first_value(...)
NameGuid = MinNameGuid
```

Note : The query was an answer to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373082/query-to-return-unique-values-when-one-of-column-value-is-repeating/20374182#20374182)

Comment: You can do something similar with a subquery and `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: I tried replacing first_value() with row_number() but i am getting `Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: It's not that simple - you'll need to compute row_number in a subquery and join to that.  I don't have a full answer but thought that might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in SQL Server 2008 to replicate `First_Value` function

```
;with CTE(NameGuid, Name, AncestorGuid, ProductGuid, PathLength) AS
(
  select 
  NameGuid, 
  Name, 
  AncestorGuid, 
  ProductGuid, 
  PathLength, 
-- take every row from original query with the same Name as this,
-- order those rows by PathLength (and NameGuid to disambiguate)
-- and return the NameGuid of the first row in that "partition"
-- first_value(NameGuid) over (partition by Name order by PathLength asc, NameGuid asc) MinNameGuid
 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by PathLength asc, NameGuid asc) MinNameGuid
from ( 
    ... your original query ...
)a
)
Select c.NameGuid, c.Name, c.AncestorGuid, c.ProductGuid,
c.PathLength,c1.NameGUID
from CTE c
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT NAMEGUID,Name from CTE where MinNameGuid = 1) C1
on 
c.Name = C1.Name
where c1.NAMEGUID is not NULL
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3186d/9)