# What is the alternative of First for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reverse engineering a MS Access query that flags duplicates and then decides which one to keep based on some conditions. I found the duplicates using a group by statement. My issue is finding a way to write the conditions down. What the MS Access query did was sort by the conditions and then used the `FIRST` function to pick the row that fulfilled most of the conditions. SQL Server does not use `FIRST`, any ideas to go around `FIRST` to do this?

The best I have been able to think of was using `max(Opportunity)` which would return an instance of the field but without any of the criteria to pick the duplicate.

MS Access query:

```
SELECT Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1.[RequFX_Req_ID_Cont_ID:],
 First(Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1.[Oppty ID]) AS [FirstOfOppty ID], First(Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1.[Op id]) AS [FirstOfOp id], "Surving Oppty" AS Dup_A_Resolution
FROM Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1
GROUP BY Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1.[RequFX_Req_ID_Cont_ID:], "Surving Oppty";
```

`[FirstOfOppty ID]` and `[FirstofOp id]` are the ones that have to be picked by the conditions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377834/alternate-for-first-value-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Frankly your  query is not clear to me.I will suggest you to play with Window function like  Row_number ,Rank.Also once you can try `First_Value`,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Using ROW_NUMBER() to identify duplicate rows:

```
SELECT t1.[RequFX_Req_ID_Cont_ID:], t1.[Oppty ID] AS [FirstOfOppty ID],
    t1.[Op id] AS [FirstOfOp id], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.[RequFX_Req_ID_Cont_ID:] ORDER BY t1.[Oppty ID]) AS ROWNUMBER
FROM Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1 t1
WHERE ROWNUMBER > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use window function `RANK() ... OVER()`. The partition corresponds to the non-aggregated columns of your original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [RequFX_Req_ID_Cont_ID:],
        [Oppty ID] AS [FirstOfOppty ID], 
        [Op id] AS [FirstOfOp id],
        "Surving Oppty",
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1.[RequFX_Req_ID_Cont_ID:] ORDER BY Opportunity DESC) rn
    FROM Dup_A_Open_04_Temp1 t
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note: since your original query has no ordering, it is hard to tell exactly which column should be used in the `ORDER BY` clause of the window `RANK()`. Based on your description of the problem, I picked column `Opportunity`. You might need to adapt this to your exact use case.